# Spring Cloud Task: Get ExecutionId for Composed Task

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am curious is there any way to get *executionID* for Composed Task from within child task. I tried to use *TaskExecutionListener* in subtask, but it returns Id for that subtask, but not the "general one".

Answer (score 0):

The composed-task-runner doesn't support this behavior at this time.  However I have created a story to add this feature.  https://github.com/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/composed-task-runner/issues/28